# CORS policies are not working as they should in Golang + Gin framework

Tags: go, frontend, cors, backend, go-gin

I'm trying to deploy a microservice that aims for messaging between users.
When I access my URL for this service from my frontend application made with React, I get the following error message in the developer console:

> Access to fetch at 'http://my-server-ip:8080/conversations?userID=1'
> from origin 'http://same-server-ip' (this is my frontend) has been
> blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your
> needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
> CORS disabled

It is worth mentioning that the api "http://my-server-ip:8080/conversations?userID=1" uses the get verb. The parameter is passed and the user obtains a list of their recent conversations.

This is tested in postman, everything works fine, but I understand that postman does things differently with headers.

I would greatly appreciate your help with this problem.

This is my code from my `main.go` file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "appchat/db"
    "appchat/handlers"
    "appchat/routes"

    "time"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {

    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins: []string{"*", "http://my-server-dns", "http://my-server-ip"},
        AllowMethods: []string{"GET", "POST"},
        AllowHeaders: []string{"Content-Type,access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-headers"},
        MaxAge:       12 * time.Hour,
    }))

    db.ConnectToMongoDB()
    defer db.CloseMongoDB()

    handlers.InitMessagesCollection(db.Client, "mensajeriaDB", "Mensajes")
    handlers.InitConversationsCollection(db.Client, "mensajeriaDB", "Conversaciones")

    routes.SetupMessageRoutes(r)
    routes.SetupConversationRoutes(r)


    r.Run(":8080") 
}
```

I also tried the following way described in the official gin github documentation:

```golang
func main() {

    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(cors.Default())

    db.ConnectToMongoDB()
    defer db.CloseMongoDB()

    handlers.InitMessagesCollection(db.Client, "mensajeriaDB", "Mensajes")
    handlers.InitConversationsCollection(db.Client, "mensajeriaDB", "Conversaciones")

    routes.SetupMessageRoutes(r)
    routes.SetupConversationRoutes(r)

    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

This configuration is supposed to:

'**note**: while `Default()` allows all origins, `DefaultConfig()` does not and you will still have to use AllowAllOrigins'

Answer (score 3):

Your header array is not correctly constructed. This:

```
AllowHeaders: []string{"Content-Type,access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-headers"},
```

should be:

```
AllowHeaders: []string{"Content-Type", "access-control-allow-origin", "access-control-allow-headers"},
```

But you shouldn't do this at all. Instead, you should construct and then modify the default config. You don't need to add the CORs headers manually.  Also, it doesn't make sense to have both the star ("*") origin and other origins. You should have one or the other:

```
corsConfig := cors.DefaultConfig()
corsConfig.AllowAllOrigins = true
corsConfig.AddAllowHeaders("Authorization") // Use the "Add" method if you need an extra header (not a CORS header)
```

or:

```
corsConfig := cors.DefaultConfig()
corsConfig.AllowOrigins = []string{"http://my-server-dns", "http://my-server-ip"},
corsConfig.AddAllowHeaders("Authorization") // Use the "Add" method
```

See: https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors/tree/master#using-defaultconfig-as-start-point

Comment: If Gin's CORS middleware validated user input like origins and header (like [jub0bs/fcors](https://github.com/jub0bs/fcors) does ), [this wouldn't happen](https://go.dev/play/p/dEXw2OdhdoU).

Comment: Thanks for your time.
I noticed using the curl command to view the headers and found that there was a redirect as a response in my request.

It was because I was requesting:

conversationGroup.GET("/", handlers.GetConversations)

but it had to be:
conversationGroup.GET("", handlers.GetConversations)

Comment: @ManuelGokor the route "/todos/" is not strictly the same route as "/todos". By default, gin will send a redirect if there's a match with or without. See: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.RedirectTrailingSlash
Is your CORS issue is resolved by the answer? If so, please accept.